# Trying to understand DHCP for my particular situation

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

Although I have read articles on networking, I still fail to understand it practically, so I would very much appreciate someone explain my questions. (I know the theoretical definitions, I just don't know how they apply to the real world)

Regarding DHCP, I was first going to ask how a computer gets assigned their IP address but the answer is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/575895/how-do-routers-assign-ip-addresses), now in my particular case my computer gets assigned an IP of the form 10.10.B.x/24. Why does it not get assigned 192.168.1.x/24?? Is there a table in the DHCP? And is there a way to change these allowable addresses?

Now for the real theme of this question. I have the situation drawn in the upper part of this
[image: local network]
PC B and PC A are connected through a cable and they both use static IP addresses (of the form 192.168.1.x/24) . PC A and M (an embedded machine)are connected through another cable and they both use static IP Addresses (of the form 10.10.A.x/24) (notice that A and B are different, so I guess they are different networks from the wireless one?? ) Wireless is not used here. Everything is working well.

I want to change the configuration to the lower part of the drawing. 
This time PC A and M stay the same, but PC B and PC A are to communicate wirelessly. PC A does not have wireless capability. 
So I plan to put a wireless Access Point (AP) connected with a cable to PC A.

Now the questions.

PC A as I said has a static IP address of form 192.168.1.x/24. Should I assign a (192.168.1.x)static IP address to the AP too?  How do I access the AP and assign the IP?

Even if I do that, PC B wireless IP is DHCP and of the form 10.10.B.x, so how can I communicate PC B with PC A?? should the static IPs of the AC and PC A change to 10.10.B.x/24 form??

My objective is PC A is running a web server and I want to throw requests to it from PC B.

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer @TOOGAM. From what I am understanding (which is few :( networking seems so difficult for me, my apologies) PC B can keep its 192.168.1.x/24 IP when connected to the wireless access point, but this access point has to have *router* capabilities in order to transmit info to the other side (the wireless 10.10B.x/24). Is this correct?

In the current situation (without wireless) I assign the PC B (static) IP address to a client application running in PCA to throw a request to the server in PCB and it works without problem.

In the new situation (with the wireless access point-router) which IP should I use to throw the request to the server in B???

Comment: The accuracy of your diagrams is questionable.  What is M?  Is it just a modem, or does it also have router functionality, i.e. NAT, firewall?  Does PC-A actually have two Ethernet ports?  Why is "DHCP" in your title when there seems to be no DHCP server in your current setup?

Comment: @sawdust M is a machine (embedded so not a "personal" computer-but not really that relevant since it is not going to change). PC-A does have two ethernet ports. DHCP is there because that is what the wireless network that I want to use in my goal uses.(so I suppose that is what I will use)

Comment: So where is the DHCP server in your *"particular situation"*?  Why is your question tagged with `router` when there seems to be none in your diagrams or descriptions?

Comment: @sawdust that is precisely one question I also would like to ask. Where are DHCP servers located? (I don't understand networking so I can't answer but I suppose it somewhere in the setup of the wireless network we use here)

Comment: and I want to emphasize that I completely confess my ignorance in networking. I have read tutorials, which explain the theory and I can repeat it by heart but never understood the meaning or the practical use of them. Sorry about my ignorance. that is why I am asking

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it not get assigned 192.168.1.x/24??  Is there a table in the DHCP?

DHCP is a protocol.  The term "protocol" is often used to describe a standard set of communications that are used by devices on a network, or a standard way that they communicate.

Part of the DHCP protocol specifies that an IP address will be provided for the end system to use.  The "DHCP server", which is a piece of software (that might be run on a device like a "wireless access point" or some other router) will decide what IP addresses to use.

> And is there a way to change these allowable addresses?

Yes.  There is typically a way to configure which IP addresses the DHCP server will use.

> PC A as I said has a static IP address of form 192.168.1.x/24. Should I assign a (192.168.1.x)static IP address[...]?

If you have some devices using 192.168.1.x and other devices using 10.x.x.x, then they are in different subnets.  In between each subnet, you should have a router that will "route" the traffic between the subnets.  A common setup is for a device, such as a wireless access point, to have several ports marked as "LAN" which act like a network "switch", so all those ports can be on one subnet, but then another port is labelled "WAN" and is using a different subnet.

The exact details, though, can often be configured, and so they can vary between devices.

> Should I assign a [...] IP address to the AP too?

You will want to know the IP address of the access point, in order to help with the next question.  However, you often don't need to assign it.  Often the access points will be pre-configured to assign their own IP address by using DHCP on a WAN port, and they will be pre-configured to use a different subnet on the LAN ports.  So manually assigning might be possible, but is often unnecessary (and often undesirable).

Keep in mind that your AP might have multiple IP addresses.  (One per subnet.)

> How do I access the AP and assign the IP?

Typically you figure out an IP address that it uses, and access that in a web browser.  (e.g., maybe point your web browser at http://192.168.1.1)

You might need to connect via a LAN port, or perhaps WLAN (wireless), but not a WAN port.  Or maybe WLAN will also have configuration disabled.  This is an attempt to help with security.  (Whether there is such a limitation, or not, may depend on how your device is configured.)

To find the default IP address, you might need to search online for "default IP address" along with the make and model of your device.

> Even if I do that, PC B wireless IP is DHCP and of the form 10.10.B.x, so how can I communicate PC B with PC A??

You'll need a router.

> should the static IPs of the AC and PC A change to 10.10.B.x/24 form??

Often, a router will perform NAT.  Network Address Translation allows devices using one subnet (e.g. 192.168.x.x) to be "translated" so that they are using an IP address on another subnet (like 10.x.x.x).

> My objective is PC A is running a web server and I want to throw requests to it from PC B.

Before trying to run a web server, I suggest making sure you can have devices ping each other.  At some point, if this is to be a public web server, you may need to delve into "port forwarding" on a router (which may be a device called a "firewall" or "modem").

Some helpful hints:

- Keep in mind that your AP may have multiple IP addresses (typically one per subnet)
- You often want just one DHCP server on a subnet.  Otherwise, you may get "race conditions" that may cause problems soon, or eventually.  You can have multiple DHCP servers, but if you do, the easy way to set this up is to make sure that the addresses they hand out don't overlap.
- For any subnet that you want to connect to the Internet, you will want a "default gateway" which is in that subnet.
- If you have a computer using Microsoft Windows, you can run "IPConfig /all" and you should see a line that says the IP address of the DHCP server that provided the computer with an address (if the computer is using DHCP).  If you wonder if you have multiple DHCP servers, then DHCPLoc.exe can be used to help determine that.  (To use that, you might need to download DHCPLoc.exe from Microsoft.)

Comment: The 'default gateway' should be in any network one wants to connect to another network and not just the Internet.

Comment: @TOOGAM If I connect the wireless access point to the PC B and make a ipconfig/all is the "gateway IP" the IP of the access point?

Comment: Probably/maybe.  You don't actually include the Internet in your drawings.  In general, the Default Gateway will be the IP address of the device that traffic must go through next, in order to get traffic out to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to understand DHCP for my particular situation

In your first diagram and its description you have three hosts and two ad hoc network connections.
You report that all four Ethernet interfaces have been assigned static IP addresses.
Therefore dynamic IP addressing is not used, and there is no need for a DHCP server.

> I want to change the configuration to the lower part of the drawing ... PC B and PC A are to communicate wirelessly.

A change from a wired connection to a wireless connection only affects the physical layer of the network.
If you want to continue to use static IP addressing, then you can.
There is no requirement to have a DHCP server and use dynamic IP addressing with WiFi (or Ethernet).
So there is absolutely no need in your *"particular situation"* to add a DHCP server.

> PC A does not have wireless capability. So I plan to put a wireless Access Point (AP) connected with a cable to PC A.

There is more than one way to provide WiFi access.
A wireless access point in an external box connected by Ethernet is the non-intrusive method to provide WiFi to `PC A`.
The alternative is to add a wireless interface (e.g. a PCIe card or USB adapter), and install it as a WAP rather than a wireless client.
Regardless of the hardware, static IP addresses can be used instead of dynamic.

---

> PC A as I said has a static IP address of form 192.168.1.x/24. Should I assign a (192.168.1.x)static IP address to the AP too?

A WAP (or wireless router's LAN interface) typically defaults to a known static IP address for configuration.
If you add a wireless interface, then configure it with a static IP address.

> How do I access the AP and assign the IP?

An ad hoc Ethernet connection and a web-interface is typical.  Refer to the unit's manual.

> Even if I do that, PC B wireless IP is DHCP and of the form 10.10.B.x, so how can I communicate PC B with PC A??

There should be no rule that prevents changing this interface on `PC B` to a static IP address.
You can choose to continue to use static IP addresses like the wired connection, or use dynamic IP addresses (assuming that there is a DHCP server).

> should the static IPs of the AC and PC A change to 10.10.B.x/24 form??

You can use any [private IP address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) that you want.

> My objective is PC A is running a web server and I want to throw requests to it from PC B.

That does not impose any additional layer 1 or 2 network requirements.

---

> ... in my particular case my computer gets assigned an IP of the form 10.10.B.x/24. Why does it not get assigned 192.168.1.x/24??

Apparently the DHCP server is configured to hand out Class A IP addresses rather than Class C.
See [Private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

> Is there a table in the DHCP?

The DHCP server is typically configured with a range of IP addresses that it can hand out.
There may also be a list of restricted or reserved addresses that are excluded from that range.

> And is there a way to change these allowable addresses?

Depends of the DHCP server, but the answer should be yes.

---

> Where are DHCP servers located?

That typically depends on what kind of network equipment that you are using.
The typical home or small office situation uses an all-in-one box (aka wireless router) that contains a wireless access point, a firewall, NAT server, DHCP server, DNS server, a switch on the LAN side, and optionally a (cable or xDSL) modem on the WAN side.
Otherwise the DHCP server program can be hosted by any computer on the network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have some constraints: 1) PC A can not be modified to add a wireless interface. 2) PC B is a particular type of computer: A Hololens, and I am not sure it can be set with a static IP